# How can I save a font/font height combination for easy access?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I oftentimes encounter fonts in documents that I need to reuse a lot and it's rather cumbersome to manually select the font, font height, and later switch back to standard font.

Is there a good solution for this use case?

For example, I'd like to switch to `Times New Roman/13.5` with a single button press and then go back `to Arial/12` with another button press.

Ideally, I'd have a bar somewhere where I could store a few of those fonts for easy switching back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by [creating a custom style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563).

To create a new style

1. Format a block of text in the style you desire
2. Right-click on the formatted text. When the popup toolbar appears, click the style button then *Create a Style*
3. Name the new style and click *Ok*

The new style will appear in Styles section of the Home toolbar and can be quickly applied to future text by placing the cursor in the desired text block and clicking the style.